# SQL Teradata Delete performance

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a simple but large table in TD:

```
CREATE SET TABLE TABLE1 ,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     MAP = TD_MAP1
     (
      party INTEGER,
      cd SMALLINT)
PRIMARY INDEX ( party );
```

I need to perform a delete:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE cd<0 AND cd<>-212;
```

Tried adding NUSI to cd:

```
CREATE INDEX (cd) ON TABLE1 ;
```

Bud that did not help.
Any advice how to increase performance?
Thanks, R.

Comment: The optimizer will use the NUSI only if Where-condition is very selective. What's the number of rows in this table how many will be deleted? Any other indexes? What does Explain show?

Comment: You've got this table defined with fallback, which means the same set of rows in the backup table must also be deleted.